# Is there a solution to my error with Wday function from Lubridate

Tags: r, lubridate

[image]

```
date_diff <- ifelse(wday(today(), label = TRUE) == "Mon", 3, 1)

date_prior <- str_replace_all(today() - date_diff, pattern = "-", replacement = "")
```

I keep receiving the error  below while trying to run the script above.

> Error in wday(today(), label = TRUE) : unused argument (label = TRUE)

Comment: Use `lubridate::wday`, you are probably using `data.table::wday`. Check output for `data.table::wday(today(), label = TRUE)` and `lubridate::wday(today(), label = TRUE)`